# Error when using unsafeHTML with lit-element

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

This is my code:

```
import {customElement, LitElement, html, property, css} from 'lit-element';
import {unsafeHTML} from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js';

@customElement('my-component')
export class myComponent extends LitElement {
  render() {
    const markup = '<div>Some HTML to render.</div>';
    return html`
      ${unsafeHTML(markup)}
    `;
  }
}
```

But when I run on browser, I get an error like this:

```
part => { if (!(part instanceof NodePart)) { throw new Error('unsafeHTML can only be used in text bindings'); } const previousValue = previousValues.get(part); if (previousValue !== undefined && isPrimitive(value) && value === previousValue.value && part.value === previousValue.fragment) { return; } const template = document.createElement('template'); template.innerHTML = value; // innerHTML casts to string internally const fragment = document.importNode(template.content, true); part.setValue(fragment); previousValues.set(part, { value, fragment }); }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqqBW.png)

My code is so simple but I still got the error, so can anyone suggest to me, how to make it work.

Comment: The error you're mentioning is shown _in place_ of the directive and not in the console, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is shown in the DOM where it was rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of [error](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/Polymer/lit-html/issues/1015) is often caused by multiple versions of lit-html interacting in the same project. A common scenario is when you start using `LitElement` (which internally uses a version of `lit-html`) and then install `lit-html` separately to be able to use the built-in directives. This sometimes can result in a duplication, easily fixable by running

```sh
$ npm dedupe
```

Also, for yarn users:

```sh
$ yarn install --flat
```

can be of help in this case.

Comment: It works, it because I duplicate importing unsafeHTML from lit-html, my friend include once from another component, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what caused me to see the error,

> unsafeHTML can only be used in text bindings

in 2023 using Lit v3:

- Following [Lit v1 `unsafeHTML()` documentation](https://lit.dev/docs/v1/lit-html/template-reference/#unsafehtml),

  ```
  import { unsafeHTML } from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js'
  ```

  the error occurs.
- Following [Lit v3 `unsafeHTML()` documentation](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#unsafehtml),

  ```
  import { unsafeHTML } from "lit/directives/unsafe-html.js"
  ```

  there is no error.